# Setting style of \item as per AwesomeCV template

Tags: multicolumn, awesome-cv

I'm a beginner in LaTeX, and I was trying to edit a template to make my Resume.
I'm using [the Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template, as present in [ShareLatex](http://sharelatex.com).

In this, I need to make a bulleted list of a few entries in 2 columns.
It appears like:

[image]

exactly the way I want. But it doesn't match the style of rest of the resume.
I have used

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

to achieve the above. How do I ensure the template font size/style applies to the above entries?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Thanks! This is a template from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv) which I'm directly editing in their website. If you put the above code at the bottom of any file in the 'resume' folder, and in 'awesome-cv.cls' file, if you add ```\usepackage{multicol}```, and compile it, you can regenerate my problem. How do I add it to the above question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the way class `awesome-cv` handles the fonts. Let us have a look for example for the definitions of the skills:

```
% For elements of skill
\newcommand*{\skilltypestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\skillsetstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{text} #1}}
```

and command `\cvskill`:

```
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

Therefore you have to add own fontspecifications to your `multicols`. In the simplest way you can do this with:

```
{ % start group for font
% \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont
  \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\bodyfontlight\color{text} % <======================
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 2 text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 3 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
} % end group
```

With the following MWE (please add one next time you ask)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
%\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parallel}


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color


\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~--~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CV/RESUME CONTENT
%   Each section is imported separately, open each file in turn to modify content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Education}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cventries}

%------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something else} % Degree
{University} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Another one} % Degree
{College} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}


%------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Skills}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cvskills}

%------------------------------------------------

\cvskill
{Programming} % Category
{Python, C/C++, Scala, JAVA, Node.JS, OCaml, LaTeX} % Skills

%------------------------------------------------

\cvskill
{Web} % Category
{Django with Python, Express with Node.JS, HTML5, LESS} % Skills

%------------------------------------------------

\cvskill
{Languages} % Category
{Korean, English, Japanese, Chinese} % Skills

%------------------------------------------------

\end{cvskills}

\cvsection{Skills}
{ % start group for font
% \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont
  \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\bodyfontlight\color{text}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 2 text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 3 text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text text text 
          text text text text text text text text text text 
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
        \item item 6
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
} % end group

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]