# I can't change the font in awesome-cv

Tags: fonts, environments, awesome-cv

[Latex Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/575Ej.png)

[image]

How do I change the font in the list under Coursework to match the font in the rest of the latex document using awesome-cv?

Comment: Looks like the same question here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419007/226

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, copy your code directly in the question, not as an image, it would be easier for someone to check and improve it.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419007/16550 I think your question is a possible duplicate one? Do you agree?